# In Roblox Lua, I have a global variable that isn't working, a silent error that stops execution, and some other general bullcrap

Tags: server, module, lua, local, roblox

Let me explain what I want to do. I have a player level module with all of the player stats that I need. I want this table to be available to module scripts and server scripts to edit and read, and for local scripts to read. I want a menu module script to be able to edit this. What I have done is created a communication system that takes the table from the module script, makes it into a _G property, and can give that global variable to local scripts when requested. I have created a menu script that used to work until I changed some things around, and now only opens once (due to said silent error). My local script that is supposed to add buttons from the level object to a GUI gives a "tried to call property of null" error even with my communication system. I have debugged this for days and made very little progress. I feel that I can do no more with my current knowledge without remaking everything without knowing what the problem was in the first place, which would be big pain in the buttocks and might not solve the problem. I will now provide all of my code that relates to each other and hope some angelic being from the heavens can find my (likely to be many) mistakes.
*Prepares to get dismembered by more experienced Roblox Studio programmers.*

I know I should be asking this on Roblox Developer's Forum, but I got demoted after some inactivity and don't have the time to grind and get my rank back up to be able to ask questions again.

**(StarterCharacterScripts.HandleCommunication (Server):**

```
local replicatedStorage = game.ReplicatedStorage

-- Remote Function to request data from the client
local requestClientData = Instance.new("RemoteFunction")
requestClientData.Name = script.Parent.Name.. "RequestClientData"
requestClientData.Parent = replicatedStorage
local sendData = Instance.new("BindableFunction")
sendData.Name = script.Parent.Name.. "sendData"
sendData.Parent = replicatedStorage
_G[script.Parent.Name.."Level"] = {}

local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local Level
-- Function to handle client requests
requestClientData.OnServerInvoke = function(player, requestData)
    return Level
end
sendData.OnInvoke = function(senData)
    if (typeof(senData) == "boolean") then
        return Level
    elseif (typeof(senData) == "table") then
        if (Level) then
            return 0
        end
        Level = senData
        _G[script.Parent.Name.."Level"] = Level
    end
end
```

**StarterCharacterScripts.MenuScript (Local):**

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local sendToServerFunction = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild(game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name.. "RequestClientData")
local function sendToServer(dataToSend)
    local response = sendToServerFunction:InvokeServer(dataToSend)
    return response
end
local dictionary = sendToServer(true)
dictionary = dictionary.knownWords
local scrollingFrame = script.Parent
local searchBox = script.Parent.SearchBox -- Assuming you have an input box for searching
local propertyButtons = {} -- Store references to property buttons
for _, child in pairs(script.Parent:GetChildren()) do
    if child.Name == "word" then
        child:Destroy()
    end
end
-- Function to create property buttons
local function createPropertyButton(word, translation)
    local buttonClone = script.Parent["clone button"]:Clone()
    buttonClone.Name = "word"
    buttonClone.Text = word .. " = " .. translation
    buttonClone.Parent = scrollingFrame
    table.insert(propertyButtons, buttonClone) -- Store the button reference
    buttonClone.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
        local chatBar = player.PlayerGui.Chat.Frame.ChatBarParentFrame.Frame.BoxFrame.Frame.ChatBar
        if chatBar then
            chatBar:CaptureFocus()
            local currentText = chatBar.Text
            if currentText ~= "" then
                currentText = currentText .. " "
            end
            chatBar.Text = currentText .. word
        end
    end)
end

local function populatePropertyButtons()
    print("Populating")
    for word, translation in pairs(dictionary) do
        createPropertyButton(word, translation)
    end
end

local function updateButtonVisibility(searchText)
    -- Iterate through property buttons
    for _, button in pairs(propertyButtons) do
        local buttonTranslation = button.Text:match("= (.-)$") -- Extract the translation from button text
        if buttonTranslation then
            if searchText == "" or buttonTranslation:lower():find(searchText:lower()) then
                button.Visible = true -- Show button if it matches the search
            else
                button.Visible = false -- Hide button if it doesn't match the search
            end
        end
    end
end

-- Function to handle search input
local function handleSearchInput()
    local searchText = searchBox.Text
    updateButtonVisibility(searchText)
end

-- Connect the search input function to the InputChanged event of the search box
searchBox:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Text"):Connect(handleSearchInput)

-- Initial population of buttons
populatePropertyButtons()
```

**Game.ReplicatedStorage.Menu (Module):**

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local sendToServerFunction = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild(game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name.. "RequestClientData")
local function sendToServer(dataToSend)
    local response = sendToServerFunction:InvokeServer(dataToSend)
    return response
end
local dictionary = sendToServer(true)
dictionary = dictionary.knownWords
local scrollingFrame = script.Parent
local searchBox = script.Parent.SearchBox -- Assuming you have an input box for searching
local propertyButtons = {} -- Store references to property buttons
for _, child in pairs(script.Parent:GetChildren()) do
    if child.Name == "word" then
        child:Destroy()
    end
end
-- Function to create property buttons
local function createPropertyButton(word, translation)
    local buttonClone = script.Parent["clone button"]:Clone()
    buttonClone.Name = "word"
    buttonClone.Text = word .. " = " .. translation
    buttonClone.Parent = scrollingFrame
    table.insert(propertyButtons, buttonClone) -- Store the button reference
    buttonClone.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
        local chatBar = player.PlayerGui.Chat.Frame.ChatBarParentFrame.Frame.BoxFrame.Frame.ChatBar
        if chatBar then
            chatBar:CaptureFocus()
            local currentText = chatBar.Text
            if currentText ~= "" then
                currentText = currentText .. " "
            end
            chatBar.Text = currentText .. word
        end
    end)
end

local function populatePropertyButtons()
    print("Populating")
    for word, translation in pairs(dictionary) do
        createPropertyButton(word, translation)
    end
end

local function updateButtonVisibility(searchText)
    -- Iterate through property buttons
    for _, button in pairs(propertyButtons) do
        local buttonTranslation = button.Text:match("= (.-)$") -- Extract the translation from button text
        if buttonTranslation then
            if searchText == "" or buttonTranslation:lower():find(searchText:lower()) then
                button.Visible = true -- Show button if it matches the search
            else
                button.Visible = false -- Hide button if it doesn't match the search
            end
        end
    end
end

-- Function to handle search input
local function handleSearchInput()
    local searchText = searchBox.Text
    updateButtonVisibility(searchText)
end

-- Connect the search input function to the InputChanged event of the search box
searchBox:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Text"):Connect(handleSearchInput)

-- Initial population of buttons
populatePropertyButtons()
```

**StarterCharacterScripts.Level (Module):**

```
local module
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local sendToServerFunction = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild(script.Parent.Name.. "sendData")
local function sendToServer(dataToSend)
    local response = sendToServerFunction:Invoke(dataToSend)
    return response
end
if ((not sendToServer(true)) or not sendToServer(true).firePower) then
    module = {}
else 
    module = sendToServer(true)
    sendToServer(module)
end

--if (not _G[script.Parent.Name.."Level"]) then
--  _G[script.Parent.Name.."Level"] = {}
--end
module = _G[script.Parent.Name.."Level"]
local replicatedStorage = game.ReplicatedStorage
local dictionary = require(replicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Dictionary"))
if (not module.firePower) then
    module.XP = 5

    module.evocation = 0
    module.vibromancy = 0
    module.necromancy = 0
    module.telemancy = 0
    module.sorcery = 0
    module.wizardry = 0
    module.vocabulary = 0

    module.evocationPoints = 0
    module.vibromancyPoints = 0
    module.necromancyPoints = 0
    module.telemancyPoints = 0
    module.sorceryPoints = 0
    module.wizardryPoints = 0
    module.vocabularyPoints = 0

    module.firePower = 1
    module.coldPower = 1
    module.lifePower = 1
    module.necroticPower = 1
    module.forcePower = 1
    module.spacePower = 1
    module.soundPower = 1
    module.lightPower = 1
    module.spiritPower = 1
    module.summonPower = 1
    module.psychicPower = 1
    module.enchantPower = 1

    module.learnedWords = {}
    module.knownWords = {}
end

module.levelUp = function() 
    module.XP = module.XP + 1
end
module.purchaseLevel = function(Type)
    if (module.XP >= 1) then
        module.XP = module.XP - 1
        module[Type] = module[Type] + 1
        module[Type.. "Points"] = module[Type.. "Points"] + 1
    end
end
module.purchaseWord = function(word,Type)
    if (module[Type.."Points"] >= 1) then
        module[Type.. "Points"] = module[Type.. "Points"] - 1
        table.insert(module.learnedWords,word)
        module.knownWords[word] = dictionary:returnAll()[word]
        local clone = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(script.Parent).PlayerGui.ScreenGui.SpellBook.MenuScript:Clone()
        clone.Parent = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(script.Parent).PlayerGui.ScreenGui.SpellBook
        clone.Enabled = true
        return true
    end
    return false
end


return module
```

**TheButtonThatOpensTheMenu.OpenMenu (Local):**

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game.ReplicatedStorage
local button =  script.Parent
local Menu = require(ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Menu"))

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    Menu.OpenMenu(game.Players.LocalPlayer)
end)
```

Yes, I used ChatGPT to do some of the code for me, mostly GUI code (not my specialty). No, I don't think that it's part of the problem, I made most of the important code.
I will be very grateful if someone solves this.